# NGINX - This site can't be reached

Tags: nginx, centos

Recently my nginx.conf files became corrupted on a couple of CentOS web servers. I put them back together based on development versions I have, but am running into an issue where I get a "This site can't be reached." message whenever I access the site through the clustered URL or via HTTPS. It works fine when I access using the machines' network names directly, though.

[image]

Here is a sanitized version of my nginx.conf file...is anything jumping out here that I might be missing?

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
# include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$ssl_client_s_dn" "$ssl_client_i_dn"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            off;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        location /DemoSite/signalr/Latest/ {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/Latest(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
        location = /DemoSite/Latest {
           return 302 /DemoSite/Latest/;
        }
        location /DemoSite/Latest/ {
            root /var/www/DemoSite/Latest/wwwroot;
            if ($query_string ~ "^([^&]*)_dc=([^&]*)$") {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri?;
            }
            try_files $uri @proxy_latest;
        }
        location @proxy_latest {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/Latest(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }

        location /DemoSite/signalr/1.0.0.0/ {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/1.0.0.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
        location = /DemoSite/1.0.0.0 {
           return 302 /DemoSite/1.0.0.0/;
        }
        location /DemoSite/1.0.0.0/ {
            root /var/www/DemoSite/1.0.0.0/wwwroot;
            if ($query_string ~ "^([^&]*)_dc=([^&]*)$") {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri?;
            }
            try_files $uri @proxy_1_0_0_0;
        }
        location @proxy_1_0_0_0 {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/1.0.0.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }

        location /DemoSite/signalr/3.0.2.0/ {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/3.0.2.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
        location = /DemoSite/3.0.2.0 {
           return 302 /DemoSite/3.0.2.0/;
        }
        location /DemoSite/3.0.2.0/ {
            root /var/www/DemoSite/3.0.2.0/wwwroot;
            if ($query_string ~ "^([^&]*)_dc=([^&]*)$") {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri?;
            }
            try_files $uri @proxy_3_0_2_0;
        }
        location @proxy_3_0_2_0 {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/3.0.2.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 433 ssl http2 default_server;
        location /DemoSite/Latest/signalr/ {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/Latest(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
        location = /DemoSite/Latest {
           return 302 /DemoSite/Latest/;
        }
        location /DemoSite/Latest/ {
            root /var/www/DemoSite/Latest/wwwroot;
            if ($query_string ~ "^([^&]*)_dc=([^&]*)$") {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri?;
            }
            try_files $uri @proxy_latest;
        }
        location @proxy_latest {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/Latest(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }

        location /DemoSite/1.0.0.0/signalr/ {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/1.0.0.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
        location = /DemoSite/1.0.0.0 {
           return 302 /DemoSite/1.0.0.0/;
        }
        location /DemoSite/1.0.0.0/ {
            root /var/www/DemoSite/1.0.0.0/wwwroot;
            if ($query_string ~ "^([^&]*)_dc=([^&]*)$") {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri?;
            }
            try_files $uri @proxy_1_0_0_0;
        }
        location @proxy_1_0_0_0 {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/1.0.0.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }

        location /DemoSite/3.0.2.0/signalr/ {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/3.0.2.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }
        location = /DemoSite/3.0.2.0 {
           return 302 /DemoSite/3.0.2.0/;
        }
        location /DemoSite/3.0.2.0/ {
            root /var/www/DemoSite/3.0.2.0/wwwroot;
            if ($query_string ~ "^([^&]*)_dc=([^&]*)$") {
              rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri?;
            }
            try_files $uri @proxy_3_0_2_0;
        }
        location @proxy_3_0_2_0 {
            rewrite ^/DemoSite/3.0.2.0(.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn; 
        proxy_set_header X-CERT-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Path $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Path $uri;
        }


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate "/etc/ssl/sewrver_certificate.cer";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/ssl/server_certificate.key";
        ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `listen 433` instead of `listen 443` on line 175?

Comment: That's all it was...embarassing!